# CouchDB - Deleted database does not release disk space on other cluster nodes

Tags: couchdb

I have a CouchDB cluster (2.3.1) running for years. To clean up and get some disk space back I deleted a couple of databases. On the cluster node I performed the delete operation the corresponding shard-files dropped down to a few KB.
But, surprisingly, on all other cluster nodes the original shard-file size stays as it was before.
Can someone confirm that this behaviour is expected?
And what is the right way to release the disk space on the other cluster nodes?

To delete the databases I just run following curl command:

curl -X DELETE http://node1:5984/location_2020-11

This deleted the database from the cluster. Checking the remaining size on disk

ls <couchdb_base>/data/shards/a0000000-bfffffff/location_2020-11.1604070002.couch  5 KB

Same file on node2 still remains on origin size

ls <couchdb_base>/data/shards/a0000000-bfffffff/location_2020-11.1604070002.couch  161233 KB

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I ask the same question on the apache couchdb channel on github and got an answer which worked for me (https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/4450).